# Restoring Objects in state Preservation- Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to save an object of First_view_controller in Second_view_controller by using state restoration and preservation technique without using storyboards but my app is crashing with unrecognized selector instance error. I tried to preserve NSString object it works fine but when I try to preserve an object I can see only the error. May be I am not doing it correctly please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the relevant code?

Comment: Issue Resolved I tried saving my custom object.

Answer (score 0):

While using custom object, you should implement protocol NSCoding that have methods as belows:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.state forKey:@"viewState"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.state = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"viewState"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

if I am not wrong may be you missed this methods in your implementation.

And for saving these class object code follows:

```
NSArray *documentPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ObjectStateContent.txt"];

NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray array];
[arr addObject:self.stateObject];    

[NSKeyedArchiver arr toFile:file]; 

//And for unarchive object 
    NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:file];
```

You should be very clear on saving custom object in file or any other storage is that "Object state can be saved in form of string or json etc., **object itself can not be persistent**".

Comment: @User if this solution working for you, then request you to please accept this answer so others can aware of it.